# Plotting several lines in one plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My dataset has three columns, namely date, sold, and item. 
I would like to investigate where a change in trends (like a peak or a drop) in market sales happens.

```
Date Sold Item
01/02/2018 1 socks
01/03/2018 4 t-shirts
01/04/2018 3 pants
01/04/2018 2 shirts
01/05/2018 1 socks
...
12/12/2018 21 watches
12/12/2018 35 toys
...
12/22/2018 43 flowers
12/22/2018 25 toys
12/22/2018 32 shirts
12/22/2018 70 pijamas
...
12/31/2018 12 toys
12/31/2018 2  skirts
```

To do this, I have been considering two things:

- number of total sales per date (e.g. 1 on Jan 2, 2018; 4 on Jan 3,2018; 5 on Jan 4, 2018; and so on);
- number of sales per item through time (i.e. looking at each item trend through time separately)

The first key point should be easily assessed by using groupby; the second key point should be also doable by using groupby. 
However, my difficulties are in plotting all the items in the same plot (preferable a line plot).

What I have done is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn

df = pd.read_csv("./MarketSales.csv")
sales_plot = df[Item].groupby("Sold").sum().sort_values("Sold",ascending=False).plot()
sales_plot.set_xlabel("Date")
sales_plot.set_ylabel("Frequency")
```

Unfortunately, the code above does not generate the expected results. 
The most challenging topic in Python is about the use of groupby and plot.

I hope you can help me to understand the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you `groupby` 'Sold' because you seem to be interested by the number of sold per date, so here are the two lines of codes that would address your two points:

```
df.groupby(['Date'])['Sold'].sum().plot()
#and
df.groupby(['Date','Item'])['Sold'].sum().unstack().plot()
```

Also, you may want to convert your date before with `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` to have a better visualization with time